# How to get the latest usb.ids when update-usbids no longer exists?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, init, lsusb

I had to move from Debian Jessie to Buster.  The script that runs to create a small custom boot disc runs `update-usbids` to get the latest files to copy over to the build.  However it now says `update-usbids command not found`.  Looking around people say it was removed for `systemd` but the boot disk still uses `init` (moving it to systemd is not a reality and would bloat it too much).

So the question is, how do I update the `usb.ids` file so I can keep the boot disk up to date?   If the file was some place could it just be downloaded using the `wget` command?

TIA!!

Comment: It's a normal file, yes it can be downloaded along with pci.ids: `wget http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids http://pciids.sourceforge.net/pci.ids`. Probably both need to be saved in `/usr/share/misc/`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - It seems wget mangles the file and downloads it without line breaks ends up like I edit the question with.  UPDATE:  I renamed the file and then it viewed okay, I was using midnight commander and the .1 version it didn't display correctly even with hex view.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It was midnight commander view of a .1 file not showing it correctly (even in hex view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
# For pci.ids
sudo wget -O /usr/share/misc/pci.ids http://pciids.sourceforge.net/pci.ids
# For usb.ids
sudo wget -O /usr/share/misc/usb.ids http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ArtemS.Tashkinov comment the answer is:

`wget --backups=1 -P /usr/share/misc/ http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids`

Note: if you ever use midnight commander to view a `.1` file it will not look correct (i.e. usb.ids.1).   That occurred before adding the --backups=1 option.